# create utility to cast objects to beans in java

Tags: java, class, object, casting

i am working on a helper class to pass a class instance and object to (object usually a JSON body) and can't quite get casting to work when using generic Class. if it does return class, it barks that my bean can't be cast to Java.lang.Class, or the below issue where I get a casting exception. What is the right way to do this?

```
public static Class castClass(Object o, Class c) {
    try {

        c = (Class) o;
        return c;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I assume that you want to check if an Object is an instance of a particular class type.

Comment: The method is called `castClass` and basically does `return (Class) o;` My understanding is that the method should indeed *cast* the object. The only misconception is that `Class` can't be used as a type parameter like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to cast your object to [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) but I bet you intended to cast the object to the type that `c` *represents*.

If so you should use [`Class.cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29). For example:

```
Class<String> c = String.class;
String s = c.cast(o);
```

If you want to return `null` in case it's the wrong class (as you do in your helper method) you would do as follows:

```
public static <T> T castClass(Object o, Class<T> c) {
    try {
        return c.cast(o);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: this was perfect, I had T for a minute but it didn't seem to work with whatever I was doing. Thanks!!

Comment: @aiboobe Hats off to you for finding a needle in a haystack.